# What is divergence exactly in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, distance, metric

I know about KL divergence, JS Divergence and clearly know that it is different from the divergence in calculus. I have an intutive feeling of divergence as it roughly compares the closeness of two distributions. I know that it is not a distance(maybe due to non-symmetricity like KL). But I don't know what it is exactly and how it is defined mathematically? I am a machine learning beginner So Pardon me for mistakes.